# Dynamically / iteratively build up page content

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, ajax, perl

I am planning to create a website which will let you iteratively construct an `SQL` query.

The idea is the following:

```
while(user wants more where clauses)
{
    show selection (html select) for table columns
    let user choose one column
    upon selection, show distinct values of that column
    let user choose one/multiple value(s)
}
```

I know how to handle the `SQL` part, but I am not sure how to tackle the iterative building of the page.

So my questions are:

1. What is the best method to build the page iteratively with the idea sketched above?
2. What do I do, if the user changes one of the previous selections?

The website will be build with `Perl` and I am thinking of utilizing `Ajax` for the dynamic part.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were to do this, I'd use [SQL::Abstract](https://metacpan.org/module/SQL%3a%3aAbstract).

UPDATE:

If you don't want to redraw the whole page, you're going to be using AJAX. So find yourself a JavaScript library that you feel comfortable with that includes ajax calls. Jquery has this, a bunch of others do too.  People have differing opinions on various libraries.

Anyway, your workflow looks like this:

1. user submits form
2. javascript performs client-side validation
3. javascript submits AJAX-style to the server
4. Server performs server-side validation, data manipulation, etc.
5. Server responds with data paylod
6. client updated the screen based on the contents of the payload.

So let's concentrate on 5 and 6.

Data Payload:  The X in AJAX means XML, but many apps send back JSON, or HTML.

Update the Screen:

You can apply HTML directly to the existing page by setting a tag's innerHTML or outerHTML attribute. But that doesn't update the DOM. If you don't dig around the DOM in your clcinet code, then this can suffice.  If you dig around, then you need to build nodes and add them to you page's DOM, so you might want to consider sending back JSON or XML.

So let's say that you have a div with id='generatedSQL' when your AJAX call retruns, it will fire a callback method (let's call it updateSQL()) and inside the callback you'll have code that looks approximately like:

```
$(#generatedSQL).innerHTML = theVariableHoldingTheHtml;
```

Your other option is to parse the JSONXML/etc. and using createNode(),etc, build new DOM bits and plug them into your page.  I don't have the jquery chops to write this for you. I look it up every time I need to do something like it.

If the query text is only ever display-only, and you never try to dig around in it on the client side, just use the innerHTML method, whether you pass HTML or pass JSON and generate HTML from it. If the query text is important to the inner workings of the client, then you'll need to write bunch of DOM manipulation code.

Comment: That's a nice module, but my question was aiming at the "display part", not the "query part". +1 anyway

Comment: You get a new where clause, you update the AST, generate a new SQL and display it. You either redraw the whole page, or update the div/span containing the text of the query.

Comment: @Baz was pretty clear: "I know how to handle the SQL part, but I am not sure how to tackle the iterative building of the page.". I'm also very interested in the "display part". AFAIK, the bleeding edge of Perl frontend/backend integration are https://metacpan.org/module/Galileo and https://metacpan.org/module/Farabi. None of them are directly related to your problem, though.

Comment: So his questions is "How do I generate HTML using Perl?"

Comment: @LenJaffe No, my question is how to dynamically change the content of a page without reloading it.

Comment: How much AJAX/jquery/etc. do you know?

Comment: @LenJaffe Not much. A little ajax and almost no jquery.

Comment: I just elaborated above, but I recommend finding a library to hide the   low level details of AJAX from you. jquery is about as good as the others. I was able to get up to speed with it pretty quickly, but I haven't used it since April, so I have some ring rust.

Answer (score 0):

No sure what you would be using but, if uses clicks on something then use the Onload event of the element with ajax call to script which brings back the data/content and on readystate just update the innerHTML of the container DIV.
Hope following link will help you understand the concept will give you a code to start with as well.
    http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp